# Selecting form two tables where query is conditional on result from first selection

Tags: php, mysql, multi-query

I have two tables with the following structure:
`Links    --> id, srcId, dstId, kind`
`Entities --> id, name, x, y`

I want to accomplish the following:

1. Select all entities within some coordinate range:

```
SELECT id, name, x, y
FROM Entities
WHERE x BETWEEN :xMin AND :xMax AND y BETWEEN :yMin and :yMax;
```

2. Select all links that have any of the previously selected `entities.id` as either source or destination (the actual query depends on how many entities there are that is how many times where clause is repeated hence ...):

```
SELECT id, srcId, dstId, kind
FROM Links
WHERE srcId = :srcId OR dstId = :dstId ...;
```

3. Select all entities that are either source or destination of any of the previously selected links (here id would be all `link.srcId` or `link.dstId` returned by previous query):

```
SELECT id, name, x, y
FROM Entities
WHERE id = :id ...;
```

What I then want to return is result of query 2 and 3. Now I already have this implemented in PHP with PDO as outlined above. Meaning I have this 3 step process. However I am wondering if there is a better more efficient way of achieving this?

I heard about PHP multi query, unions, joins, foreign keys however I don't know how and if they are useful in this scenario.

Because I do 3 separate queries there is also a risk of some other process changing the database while in between queries which is not desirable but tolerable at the moment.

Comment: If you want to return the result of 2 and 3, what is query 1 for?

Comment: Use a transaction to get consistent results while other processes are changing the DB.

Comment: Query 1 is so that I can get all entities within a x,y which I can use in query 2 to get the links that connect these entities

Comment: I don't see how the result of query 1 is used in query 2.

Comment: Are the IDs returned form query 1 used as `:srcId` and `:dstId`? How do you know which is source and which is dest?

Comment: I think you want a join between the queries. But it's not clear how you're combining everything into a final result, since query 2 selects different columns than query 3. Please show sample input data and the desired result.

Comment: @Barmar Yes IDs returned by 1 are used as `srcId` and `dstId`. I do not care which is source or destination I am only interested in if that particular entity with that ID is part of that link either as source or destination.

Comment: You should consider storing your coordinates as [POINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-data-formats.html)s with a [SPATIAL INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html), and using [ST_Contains](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join queries 1 and 2 with a `JOIN`

```
SELECT e.id
FROM Entities AS e
JOIN Links AS l ON e.id IN (l.srcId, l.dstId)
WHERE x BETWEEN :xMin AND :xMax AND y BETWEEN :yMin and :yMax;
```

Then use that as a subquery in query 3:

```
with selected_links AS (
    SELECT l.id, l.srcId, l.dstId
    FROM Entities AS e
    JOIN Links AS l ON e.id IN (l.srcId, l.dstId)
    WHERE x BETWEEN :xMin AND :xMax AND y BETWEEN :yMin and :yMax;
)
SELECT e.id, name, x, y
FROM Entities AS e
JOIN selected_links AS sl ON e.id IN (sl.srcId, sl.dstId)
```